# Does toCharArray prevent a String being created on the heap?

Tags: esp32, string, memory-usage, c-string

I know it's bad to use Strings due to the memory problems that can occur.
I've tried to remove all instances of strings from my code.
But I'm not sure about this line:

```
http.getString().toCharArray(ipAddressBuffer, lengthOfIPAddress);
```

Is calling `toCharArray()` enough to prevent memory problems? Or is there a string still being created on the heap?

If it's still created on the heap, how can I modify the code so it only deals with cstrings?

Here's my code:

```
void setIPAddress(char* ipAddressBuffer){
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/"); //Only allowed to call once per 5 mins.
  http.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36");
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  if (httpCode > 0) {    
    http.getString().toCharArray(ipAddressBuffer, lengthOfIPAddress);    
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
  }
  http.end();
}
```

I'm using the HTTPClient.h library btw.

Comment: BTW: Which HTTPClient library? I know one which allows for `HttpClient` objects, not for `HTTPClient`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of getString allocates and the deletes a char array in heap for a temporary String object.

For ESP8266HTTPClient and ESP32 HTTPClient library you can use `writeToStream` or `getStream()`to read the response without using String class with `getString()`, where `stream` is `WiFiClient& stream = client.getStream();`

`getStream`, returns the underlying WiFiClient. You can read the data with classic `while (stream.available()) { char c = stream.read; ... }`

`writeToStream` copies the data to a stream. My StreamLib library has a stream wrapper over a char array. It is called CStringBuilder.

Comment: One caveat to your answer: I read in the ArduinoJson documentation that [if you do `client.getStream()` you bypass the chunked transfer encoding code](https://arduinojson.org/v6/how-to/use-arduinojson-with-httpclient/#:~:text=Unfortunately%2C%20by%20using%20the%20underlying%20Stream%2C%20we%20bypass%20the%20code%20that%20handles%20chunked%20transfer%20encoding%2C%20so%20we%20must%20switch%20to%20HTTP%20version%C2%A01.0.) and that for that case you must fall back to HTTP1.0 using `useHTTP10(true)`. Did you encounter that, and is that something you could incorporate in your answer?

Comment: Or would [`writeToStream(Stream * stream)`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/23d715af1b185fac21558c907af4ff5b86526aa4/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp#L883), which [`getString()` uses internally](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/23d715af1b185fac21558c907af4ff5b86526aa4/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp#L975) be a good idea?

Comment: @hansmbakker my StreamLib has ChunkedStreamReader. see the ReadChunkedJson example. StreamLib is in the Library Manager

Answer (score 0):

`http.getString()` creates a temporary Arduino String object and fills text into dynamic memory on the heap. Calling the method `.toCharArray`copies this text to a char array, wherever you defined it. 
Immediately after that, the temporary String gets out of scope and the text on the heap is deleted again.